# Custom login page for Apache Free Radius 2fa authentication

Tags: apache, apache2.2, radius, freeradius, two-factor-authentication

For one of my projects I have to set up two factor authentication. We have Radius server set up at the back end. We have a Apache web server and JBoss application server beneath that. I have configured Apache Free Radius module which acts as a client to Radius Server. Once user authenticated, Apache web server redirects the request to application running on JBoss (using mod_jk load balancer). This set up currently works without any hassles. But, on the client side i.e. on the browser when user enters appropriate URL, Free Radius prompts for user credentials. This is purely browser dependent. Is there any way where I can use a custom web page instead of default one. I believe there must be some configuration in Free Radius module where I can use custom web page to consume user credentials. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this out of the box, since the apache module does basic authentication, i.e. it requires the credentials on each request and the browser takes care about fetching and caching the credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don;t have much knowledge on this. But with a custom web page I believe browser can still cache the user details and send it along with every subsequent request to login. Is that correct?

Comment: In fact you need some kind of mini SSL VPN. Your webpage performs the OTP authentication. Then issues a session ticket to the users browser, which is used on each request.